# what are supported STL types in tables?

Tags: ram, table, eosiocpp, c++

What are the supported STL types in tables? I'm specifically curious about `std::pair`

Comment: Can't give you an exact answer but I used pair a while ago so it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find supported c++ headers on EOSIO contract [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/libcxx). `std::pair` is defined in `libcxx/include/utility`.